# In what meaningful ways does Erlang prevent race conditions in concurrent programming?

Tags: concurrency, erlang

Reading about [concurrency in Erlang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erlang_%28programming_language%29#Concurrency_and_distribution_orientation), reminds me of the [Akka concurrency toolkit](http://akka.io/).  Both give you tools to prevent or limit [race conditions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition).  But you can send links to mutable data to other processes using the Akka toolkit, which is still unsafe.  I see Akka as a useful tool, but it does not provide *protection* against out-of-order access to objects and data leading to race-conditions, deadlock, and/or starvation.  It doesn't prevent you from writing unsafe code the way Java or C# protects you from writing most of the kinds of memory leaks you can write in C++ (you can still create memory leaks in Java by tricking the garbage collector, but it is less of a problem than having to remember to free every byte you allocate).

Does Erlang guarantee a degree of correctness, performance, and robustness in concurrent programming?  I think operating systems provide protection when accessing system resources (assuming the driver writers did their jobs well). ACID databases provide protection for reads and updates.  So it seems this is a solvable problem.  Or would a generic safe solution would erase the performance gains that concurrency provides?  Do other languages or toolkits provide the kind of concurrent safety that Erlang does (or doesn't)?

This is a follow-up question to [@Malfist's comment](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/22769/what-programming-language-generates-fewest-hard-to-find-bugs#comment37437_22783) on @user1249's answer to [What programming language generates fewest hard-to-find bugs?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/22769/what-programming-language-generates-fewest-hard-to-find-bugs).

Answer (score 19):

There are a few things that Erlang does to help with these.

- Data is immutable, so no data races
- OTP gen_servers and gen_fsm's provide a very well tested pattern for servers
- Supervisors allow for recovery from crashes
- processes are small and cheap
- Memory is allocated on a per process basis (no GC freezes)
- the erlang VM is optimised to work under very heavy loads
- Software can be updated on the fly, so no upgrade downtimes

The major thing here is that in Erlang there is no shared state that could require a lock, so there is no need for locks. It is a brilliant language for soft real time applications that need no downtime and high fault tolerance and concurrency

Comment: @JarrodRoberson: Actually, the main point is *no shared mutable state*. Sharing state is no problem if you don't mutate it. Mutable state is no problem if you don't share it.

Comment: There is also a new tool Concuerror http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FpkjKN9wTKg which lets you run your tests with all possible event orderings

Comment: I still have difficulty understanding how immutable shared state prevents out-of-order state update? Let's say two requests tries to update the same value - which one will win?